# HTML / JS "Lock / Hide" content until date set

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 / CSS  page which I want to hide / disable / lock the content on until a certaindate.

Does any one know of any HTML5 / JS ways of doing this and potentially showing a message until viewing is available.

Please ask if you need any more clarification on the function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? The problem with a simple message placed over the actual content is, that anybody can still see the full page by viewing the source code. So depending your use-case the best may be to deliver a complete different page until the date is reached.

Comment: I am using an iOS app that uses Webview.ui to render HTML5 / CSS / JS pages so viewing the source code isnt a worry as its not possible from my app. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comment. You can use this HTML, CSS and JavaScript to get this thing working.

Place the `<div>`- and `<script>`-elements as the first children of your `<body>`-element. This way it's ensured that it will be removed first thing when the date is right. If you wait for a library being loaded or place the script at the bottom of the page, the user might see it flashing for a little time.

The drawback of this is still, that the user has to load the whole page, even if he can't see it. Regarding you saying that this is an iOS app you may introduce a solution where only the locked screen is being loaded as long as it's needed, to avoid unnecessary traffic.

**HTML + JavaScript**

```
<div class="locked" id="locked"></div>
<script>    
    var end = new Date('2013-01-01');
    var now = new Date();
    if (end - now <= 0) {
        var e = document.getElementById('locked');
        e.parentElement.removeChild(e);
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
div.locked {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/NyVJP/)

Comment: Ok so displays my message up to date and then displays the content within the DIV.

Comment: This solution is to display an overlay that hides the content and on the "release" date the div gets removed on every page request. The better solution would be to show the placeholder only and deliver the real page from the "release" date. But this is something your server or your app has to handle and can't be done using client side technology.

Comment: Sounds like a workable solution to me and excatly what I can use. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SKUJj/
This fiddle locks the page for 10 seconds, and then locker hides.
You should create overflowing div for 100% width and height.

Also to know unlock time you should store it somewhere.And then do

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  //unlock the screen;
 },timeStored-Date.now())
```

Where `timeStored-Date.now()` is milliseconds to wait for unlock

Comment: Possible to put a date in rather than milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML `<input>` controls (to make a non-editable form), you can set `disabled` or `readonly` attributes on the inputs from your application code or from JS.

For other content, you should render it (from the server) the way you want it in the page. Everything in the page is viewable/ or hackable, if someone remotely wants to.

So put the lock on the server that provides it, don't expect any lock on the page to be guaranteed.